UPDATE Statement ignores INNER JOIN
I expect the SQL statement to update a limited amounts of rows, instead of every row:
UPDATE Join_Test_1
SET ANumber = 3
FROM Join_Test_1 AS ST1
INNER JOIN Join_Test_2 AS ST2 ON ST1.PKID = ST2.PKID;

I expect the statement to behave the same as the statements:
UPDATE Join_Test_1
SET ANumber = 3
FROM Join_Test_2
WHERE Join_Test_1.PKID = Join_Test_2.PKID;

UPDATE Join_Test_1
SET ANumber = 3
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Join_Test_2 
              WHERE Join_Test_2.PKID = Join_Test_1.PKID);

UPDATE Join_Test_1
SET ANumber = 3
WHERE PKID IN (SELECT PKID FROM Join_Test_2);

The statements using the WHERE clause only update the ANumber column where the PKID matches.
The statement using the INNER JOIN updates all rows in the table.
Why does the INNER JOIN not limit the number of rows updated?
Can the statement with the INNER JOIN be rewritten to use the JOIN to limit the number of rows updated?
/* Expansive Example */
CREATE TABLE Join_Test_1 (PKID SERIAL, ANumber INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE Join_Test_2 (PKID SERIAL, ANumber INTEGER);

INSERT INTO Join_Test_1 (ANumber) VALUES (1), (1);      
INSERT INTO Join_Test_2 (ANumber) VALUES (2);       

UPDATE Join_Test_1
SET ANumber = 3
FROM Join_Test_1 AS ST1
INNER JOIN Join_Test_2 AS ST2 ON ST1.PKID = ST2.PKID; -- Updates 2

SELECT * 
FROM Join_Test_1 
ORDER BY PKID;

-- 1, 3
-- 2, 3

UPDATE Join_Test_1 
SET ANumber = 1; -- Update 2

UPDATE Join_Test_1
SET ANumber = 3
FROM Join_Test_2
WHERE Join_Test_1.PKID = Join_Test_2.PKID;

SELECT * 
FROM Join_Test_1 
ORDER BY PKID;

-- 1, 1
-- 2, 3     

UPDATE Join_Test_1 SET ANumber = 1; -- Update 2

UPDATE Join_Test_1
SET ANumber = 3
WHERE PKID IN (SELECT PKID FROM Join_Test_2);

SELECT * 
FROM Join_Test_1 
ORDER BY PKID;

-- 1, 1
-- 2, 3     

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Join_Test_1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Join_Test_2;


The documentation explains the syntax of update commands in Postgres. So in your use case, I guess you want something like UPDATE Join_Test_1 AS ST1 SET ANumber = 3 FROM Join_Test_2 AS ST2 WHERE ST1.PKID = ST2.PKID;. This works as expected, at least in this sample fiddle

I don't understand what you're trying to do in this query: UPDATE  Join_Test_1 SET     ANumber = 3 FROM                Join_Test_1 AS ST1         INNER JOIN  Join_Test_2 AS ST2         ON          ST1.PKID = ST2.PKID; Are you trying to update Join_Test_1 ? or are you trying to show Join_Test_1 INNER JOIN Join_Test_2  data with Join_Test_1 modified data ? There are no sense of your question. @Jennifer

The documentation mentions the possibilities of self-joins, as the one situation where one is allowed to list the table in the form section again. Thus I was expecting to have similiar options to join directly similiar to the Microsoft T-SQL or Sybase SQL dialects.

From UPDATE: Do not repeat the target table as a from_item unless you intend a self-join (in which case it must appear with an alias in the from_item).  Look at the EXAMPLES section at the above link for how you can get around this doing a sub-select.

@ArtBindu I did try to get PostGres to update a table similiar to how I would do it in TSQL, which would be:
UPDATE Join_Test_1  SET ANumber = 1   FROM Join_Test_1 AS x   INNER JOIN Join_Test_2 AS y ON y.PKID = x.PKID;

what should be expected output for your above query ? @Jennifer

@Jennifer Does the update command in my previous comment do the intended modifications? If yes, why not use that syntax? If no, what else do you want?

@ArtBindu:
The expected output is "UPDATE 1" the output I got is "UPDATE 2".
I noted the table values in the comments under the expansive example.

@Jonas It does. The reason why I asked for the option are two fold.
On the one hand I was simply used to always formulate expressions that come down to an INNER JOIN as such.
On the other hand I am currently translating statements from Sybase to Postgres. I wondered if there was an option to not rewrite them or write them to keep the JOIN-Syntax. The knowledge will as well help in communication with my colleagues.

@JonasMetzler Version 8.1 is EOL for about 2 decades... Better to link to the current documentation

In plpgSQL there is an way to update a single table during joing as follows:
CREATE TABLE Join_Test_1 (PKID SERIAL,ANumber INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE Join_Test_2 (PKID SERIAL,ANumber INTEGER);

INSERT INTO Join_Test_1 (ANumber) VALUES (1),(1);       
INSERT INTO Join_Test_2 (ANumber) VALUES (2); 

select * from Join_Test_1;
-- 1    1
-- 2    1

select * from Join_Test_2;
-- 1    2

WITH TT AS (
    UPDATE Join_Test_1
    SET ANumber = 3
    RETURNING *
)
SELECT *
FROM TT          AS ST1
INNER JOIN 
     Join_Test_2 AS ST2
ON   ST1.PKID = ST2.PKID;
-- 1    3   1   2

SELECT * FROM Join_Test_1 ORDER BY PKID;
-- 1    3
-- 2    3

Process-01: db<>fiddle - Update During joining
Process-02: db<>fiddle - Update During joining
Process-03: db<>fiddle - Normal way

No need for a function

Arguably, when dealing with updates that involve multiple or complex joins and/or conditions - the most readable and maintainable way to do it is using the MERGE INTO syntax.
MERGE INTO Join_Test_1 target
USING ( Select     t1.pkid 
        From       Join_Test_1 t1
        Inner Join Join_Test_2 t2 ON(t2.pkid = t1.pkid)
      ) src ON(src.pkid = target.pkid)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET anumber = 3;

SELECT * FROM Join_Test_1 ORDER BY PKID;

Result:



pkid
anumber




1
3


2
1



fiddle
Just make sure that your USING query fetches unique rows to be matched...

Your UPDATE statement is simply wrong. No connection is established between the target table Join_Test_1 and the second instance Join_Test_1 AS ST1. You don't need that second instance of the target table in Postgres to begin with - except for the rare case of emulating a LEFT JOIN. See:

UPDATE statement with multiple joins in PostgreSQL

This would work:
UPDATE join_test_1
SET    anumber = 3
FROM   join_test_2 st2 USING (pkid);

I also simplified and did away with unhelpful CaMeL-case spelling. See:

Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?

But this is still a dubious statement. It all comes down to bare existence of a matching row in join_test_2. With the join you run the risk of multiple matches, which produces arbitrary results. Does not show in the simplistic example with a constant assignment (unhelpful test!), but should be avoided in any case. Don't update the same row multiple times.
The right query for the purpose is your EXISTS variant, which can be simplified to:
UPDATE join_test_1 t1
SET    anumber = 3
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT FROM join_test_2 t2 WHERE t2.pkid = t1.pkid);


You alias the table Join_Test_1, but you don't call the alias in the update.  That means the FROM statement is ignored.  You statement is the same as UPDATE Join_Test_1 SET ANumber = 3.
UPDATE  ST1
SET     ANumber = 3
FROM    Join_Test_1 AS ST1
INNER JOIN  Join_Test_2 AS ST2
ON          ST1.PKID = ST2.PKID;


This is correct for SQL Server as well, but each database does this a little differently and I don't use postgresql enough.

PostGres doesn't allow for the use of an alias behind the keyword "UPDATE".
The statement as you presented will result in this error message: "ERROR: Relation »st1« doesn't exists)"

For Postgress this should be: UPDATE  Join_Test_1 SET     ANumber = 3 FROM    Join_Test_1 AS ST1 INNER JOIN  Join_Test_2 AS ST2 ON          ST1.PKID = ST2.PKID;

Please check the link: https://dbfiddle.uk/rVxIGoaB @Jennifer It's working for me

@ArtBindu: As noted in the original post this statement in Postgres behaves differently from the intended results. Where in SQL Server TSQL and in Sybase SQL the statement will only update the matching records according to the join, PostgresSQL will update all the records!
